# Facebook DrQA error - Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False

Tags: python

I have installed DrQA - https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA

Now when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
root@app:~/DrQA# python scripts/pipeline/interactive.py
01/27/2020 03:32:02 PM: [ Running on CPU only. ]
01/27/2020 03:32:02 PM: [ Initializing pipeline... ]
01/27/2020 03:32:02 PM: [ Initializing document ranker... ]
01/27/2020 03:32:02 PM: [ Loading /root/DrQA/data/wikipedia/docs-tfidf-ngram=2-hash=16777216-tokenizer=simple.npz ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/pipeline/interactive.py", line 70, in <module>
    tokenizer=args.tokenizer
  File "/root/DrQA/drqa/pipeline/drqa.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.ranker = ranker_class(**ranker_opts)
  File "/root/DrQA/drqa/retriever/tfidf_doc_ranker.py", line 37, in __init__
    matrix, metadata = utils.load_sparse_csr(tfidf_path)
  File "/root/DrQA/drqa/retriever/utils.py", line 36, in load_sparse_csr
    return matrix, loader['metadata'].item(0) if 'metadata' in loader else None
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_collections_abc.py", line 601, in __contains__
    self[key]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 262, in __getitem__
    pickle_kwargs=self.pickle_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 739, in read_array
    raise ValueError("Object arrays cannot be loaded when "
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `load_sparse_car` function `np.load(filename)` to `np.load(filename,allow_pickle=True)` in `utils.py`.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA/issues/228